# Cannot install OctoPack on some projects

Tags: asp.net, octopus-deploy

I have a Visual Studio solution with a few ASP.NET projects. I want to install OctoPack on some of them. So far I have been able to install OctoPack on one project, but not on the others. What can be the reason?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives and then I could install OctoPack.